# Creating custom sqlalchemy types

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to save ipaddress in a table. Created a custom type as follows:

```
class MCastIP(sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator):
  impl = sqlalchemy.types.Integer
  def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
    return int(IPAddress(value))
  def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
    return IPAddress(value)
```

This seem to work fine but just wondering if I have to implement any other function to be complete. Eg: `python_type`. Is the following needed? When will this be called and how do I call explicitly and test it works?

```
def python_type(self):
   return IPAddress
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In normal usage, no, the implementation you have there is sufficient.  I have several implementations with custom types and have only ever defined the methods I "need" (typically what you are using there).

In the [examples provided by the documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/types.html#typedecorator-recipes) it is never implemented.

I confess I do not know under what circumstances (if any) it is utilized by the library natively, but I have yet to encounter a problem due to its non-implementation.  I couldn't find any uses of the method in the SQLAlchemy source (outside declarations), and suspect it is simply in place for introspection/exploratory purposes.

Comment: is there a newbie-friendly documentation exists to explain what those two methods are doing? What's param? And what's result value? I'm trying to create a time point type. Thanks.

Comment: I've bought essential SQL alchemy the 2nd edition, but it doesn't touch on such advanced topics unfortunately.